# Laravel/Lumen Tymon/JWT by Phone Number and Password

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

I'm creating an API login for my API application by using JWT. In the default code, JWT use email and password for authenticate.

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
      return 'Invalid login details';
    }
    return $token;
}
```

But now, i want to change for login by ***Phone/Email*** and ***Password***, it mean, when a request coming, i will use ***Regular expression*** to recognize that an email or phone. And then, use that's credentials for **attempt()** function.

Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found Request is Illuminate\Http\Request;
and `Request->only()` returns array.

You can get or set value using
`$credentials["email"]` or `$credentials["password"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should easily be able to do this by sending either phone or email as credentials.

```
if($regexShowsItsAnEmail) {
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']); // or simply $credentials = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]
} elseif($regexShowsItsAPhoneNumber) {
    $credentials = $request->only(['phone', 'password']); // or simply $credentials = ['phone' => $phone, 'password' => $password]
} else {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```